# How to fix React/Redux/Firebase error uploading file to storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I'm setting up a file uploader that will upload images to my firebase storage. I am using React-Redux-Firebase to do all of this. According to the [docs](http://react-redux-firebase.com/docs/storage.html), I should be able to use either the uploadFiles or uploadFile functions that come from props.firebase using firebaseConnect or getFirebase(). When I try this I get the error: **Uncaught Error: Firebase storage is required to upload files.**

```
export const addImage = (image, callback = () => {}) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
        const firebase = getFirebase();
        const imagesPath = "images";

        firebase.uploadFile(imagesPath, image).then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
            console.log("uploadTaskSnapshot", uploadTaskSnapshot);
        });

        dispatch({ type: "ADDED_IMAGE", image });
    };
};
```

The function exists when I try to console.log it. But its almost like my storage isn't set up. I have checked my firebase console and it definitely exists. I have also checked my api key settings and the storage bucket variable is correct.

Here is the set up code I am using in my index.js file and also my firebaseConfig file.

Index.js :

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import fbConfig from "./config/fbConfig";

require("dotenv").config();

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
        reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
        reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, { useFirestoreForProfile: true, userProfile: "users", attachAuthIsReady: true })
    )
);

store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById("root")
    );
});
```

fbConfig.js :

```
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import "firebase/firestore";
import "firebase/auth";

// Initialize Firebase
var config = {
    apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.firestore();
console.log("firebase", firebase);

export default firebase;
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer. I needed an extra import that would import "firebase/storage" in my index.js file.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "./store/reducers/rootReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { reduxFirestore, getFirestore } from "redux-firestore";
import { reactReduxFirebase, getFirebase } from "react-redux-firebase";
import fbConfig from "./config/fbConfig";
import "firebase/storage";

require("dotenv").config();

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    compose(
        applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({ getFirebase, getFirestore })),
        reduxFirestore(fbConfig),
        reactReduxFirebase(fbConfig, { useFirestoreForProfile: true, userProfile: "users", attachAuthIsReady: true })
    )
);

store.firebaseAuthIsReady.then(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>,
        document.getElementById("root")
    );
});
```

Comment: Did you try to import "firebase/storage" in the config.js ?